# _AppStart.cshtml and _AppEnd.cshtml in WebMatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to do some clean-up work  at the end of each Session, or whatever you want to call it. In WebMatrix/WebPages websites, you have `_AppStart.cshtml` and `_PageStart.cshtml` files.

So basically we have ways to "do stuff" when the "app starts", so to speak. Do we also have files/methods/events we can use for when the "app/site" "ends"? Maybe an `_AppEnd.cshtml` file or *something*?

Comment: I don't think so. The only way to "stop" a website is to kill the process running it. AFAIK, there is no graceful way to stop a website.

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh, I don't want to "stop" it :) I just want to perform certain actions when it's "ending", for example, when the website is not being visited.

Comment: I don't think that's how website are designed. Your user says "I would like this page please", and the server does something, resulting in an html page. There is nothing built in for a lack of traffic. You would have to make an external application on a timer that checks the traffic.